# How to make ConstraintLayout fill visible space in BottomSheetDialogFragment?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I am working on a camera viewfinder which is inside of a BottomSheetDialogFragment. This fragment starts peaked filling up the screen. I am using a constraint layout which puts the shutter button at the button horizontally centred, the issue is that you can not see the shutter button while the sheet dialogue is not fully expanded. I am wondering if there is a way to make the shutter button show at the bottom while peaked and then when the sheet dialogue gets expanded, the shutter will move to the bottom?

If I did not explain that well or want more details please let me know.

Here is the XML layout:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/photo_creator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="460dp">

    <TextureView
        android:id="@+id/photo_view_finder"
        android:layout_width="330dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/photo_flash"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/content_description"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_flash_off"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/photo_view_finder" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/photo_shutter"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/content_description"
        android:onClick="takePhoto"
        android:src="@drawable/background_photo"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/photo_view_finder"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias=".96" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/photo_switch"
        android:layout_width="36dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/content_description"
        android:onClick="switchCamera"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_camera_front"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/photo_shutter"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,10:9"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/photo_shutter"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/photo_shutter" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: if you added xml code or what you have tried so far that would have been good.

Comment: @Umair I have added the layout file. I have been trying to think of ways to handle this but have not been able to come up with anything to try yet.